# ASP.net MVC Facebook Canvas App User Location

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've create a Facebook Canvas application using the following [SDK](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/aspnet-mvc-facebook-birthday-app)

Almost everything is working well.  I've got the photo, the FB ID, name, etc.  However, I can't seem to get the login user's home town or location.  I see that according to the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/) it's included as a core field.

I need something like "John Doe from Dayton Ohio...".

I've mimic'd the `public FacebookConnection<FacebookPicture> ProfilePicture { get; set; }` with a location class including an ID and string for name to no avail.

Any help is greatly appreciated.